# Minimal key from Functional Dependancies

Tags: sql, database, relation, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have the following relation:

```
{ a , b , c , d , e , f , g , h }
```

With the following functional dependencies:

```
A -> B,C,D
A,D -> E
E,F,G -> H
F -> G,H
```

[image]

My understanding is that the minimal key for this relation is `{a,f}` , as you can reach `b,c,d,e` though `a`, and reach `g,h` from `f`.

However I am told the actual minimal key is `{a,f,e}`

Can anybody explain where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `AFE` is actually a superkey and not a (minimal) candidate key, while the only candidate key is `AF`. That `AF` is a candidate key can be easily proved by computing its closure using the [Armstrong's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms). Here is a derivation that uses the Primary and Secondary Rules:

```
1. A → B C D  (given)
2. F → G H (given)
3. A F → B C D G H (by composition of 1. and 2.)
4. A → D (by decomposition of 1)
5. A → A D (by augmentation of 4)
6. A D → E (given)
7. A → E (by transitivity of 5 and 6)
8. A F → B C D E G H (by composition of 3 and 7)
9. A F → A B C D E F G H (by augmentation of 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, turns out our lecturer was wrong!